# Setting Matplotlib MPLCONFIGDIR: consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data

Tags: matplotlib

I am using Linux server to set up a django project. I got this error: "Failed to create /var/www/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data"

Then I found $MPLCONFIGDIR are empty. So I set it like this:

```
lab@base:~$ export MPLCONFIGDIR=~/website/graph
lab@base:~$ echo $MPLCONFIGDIR
/home/lab/website/graph
```

This path is the directory where I want to store images created by Matplotlib.
Then I made sure this setting in python command line:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('MPLCONFIGDIR')
'/home/lab/website/graph'
```

BUT, in the django project which is deployed in Apache with mod_wsgi, the above-mentioned error still exits. I added the below lines:

```
import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = "/home/lab/website/graph"
print(os.environ.get('MPLCONFIGDIR'))
```

It prints "None"!

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Aha, if only I knew what to search for when I had the same problem with `mapplotlib`. I backtracked the code to the point where I found `configdir = os.environ.get('MPLCONFIGDIR')`. I guess the exception stacktrace never told me about it.

Answer (score 25):

Set the MPLCONFIGDIR in code before you import matplotlib. Make sure the directory has permissions such that it can be written to by the app.

```
import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = "/home/lab/website/graph"
import matplotlib
```

Alternatively, you could set it to a tempfile.

```
import os    
import tempfile
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = tempfile.mkdtemp()
import matplotlib
```

Comment: Thanks. This was also our case.

Comment: `mkdtemp`'s output does not get removed automatically when the execution stops. An alternative would be to use `TemporaryDirectory` from the same package. See my answer below :)

Comment: If you happen to be working on an AWS Lambda, like I was when I came looking for answers to this, use the `/tmp` folder instead.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Esteban I do something like this in modules or scripts:

```
import os

try:
    import matplotlib
except:
    import tempfile
    import atexit
    import shutil

    mpldir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    atexit.register(shutil.rmtree, mpldir)  # rm directory on succ exit

    os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = mpldir

    import matplotlib
```

This way the temporary directory is removed on exit.