# Error with executing CGI script - writable directory for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cgi, statsmodels

I know that the similar problem was solving in this topic:

[Setting Matplotlib MPLCONFIGDIR: consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827377/setting-matplotlib-mplconfigdir-consider-setting-mplconfigdir-to-a-writable-dir)

, but I have problem with executing CGI script.
I use HTML fomular to input some data, and based on these data make OLS model by statsmodels and result want print as HTML page.
If I execute python script it give me this error:

http://textuploader.com/5nrhf

Basicaly I get error - `Failed to create /var/www/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data`

I red about setting the MPLCONFIGDIR in code before you import matplotlib and ake sure the directory has permissions such that it can be written to by the app like this:

```
import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = "/home/lab/website/graph"
import matplotlib
```

or

```
import os
import tempfile
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] =tempfile.mkdtemp()
import matplotlib
```

but I don´t import matplotlib module in my script, only `CGI`,`statsmodels.api`,`MySQLdb` and `numpy`

If you want, here is my CGI script - http://textuploader.com/5nrx4

I don´t know, if I must set permissions for matplotlib folder, to can be writable by me as executro of CGI script or somehow set matplotlib folder to different path (writable by me). BTW I dont own server it is just school server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly import `matplotlib`, but `statsmodels.api` imports `pandas`, and in turn `pandas` imports `matplotlib` (you can see all tht reading through your traceback).

So, you still need to have a writable `MPLCONFIGDIR` in order to run your script. You already have the answer how to do that, but in case you want to read more about it, there is some documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#envvar-MPLCONFIGDIR) about setting `matplotlib` environment variables.

---

It should be enough to just add this in your file before you import `statsmodels.api`:

```
import os
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = "/home/lab/website/graph"
```

Comment: Well maybe silly question but I am not wery experinced with apache or python, just beginner. I must put this:
`import os`
`os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = "/some/my/path"`
`import matplotlib`
into pandas file which import matplotlib?

Also I looked on link, which you wrote and something similar I did in windows (set enviroment variable), when i start work with python and localhost.

But I connect to server through WinSCP and it use `sh shell`. I try `call /bin/sh` to run shell but gives me error and to be honest I dont know if I am doing it right or must go to admin of server.