"pre-import" python dependencies in docker image
I am building a Python 3.10 Docker image in an Ubuntu-latest GitHub action that is uploaded (by serverless.com CLI) to form an AWS lambda.  It has many Python dependencies.  With a clean install of the dependencies on my local Mac, it can take 20 seconds to import the main source file (calc.py).  Similarly, when the AWS Lambda first starts, it can take 20 seconds to import the main source file (calc.py).  If I comment out all of the dependencies or they are left in but it is a subsequent call to the AWS Lambda then the calc.py file is imported very quickly (< 1 second).
I want to run an initial import in the Docker container to get the Python dependencies to "pre-compile" so that when the image is started by the AWS Lambda it is "warmed up" and ready to go instead of taking 20+ seconds to serve its first request.
I have the following Dockerfile, but the line RUN python -c "from src.calc import process_payload" does not seem to have any effect on the AWS Lambda despite working in my local environment.
# Using the SHA hash as suggested by: https://snyk.io/blog/best-practices-containerizing-python-docker/#https://snyk.io/blog/best-practices-containerizing-python-docker/#1. Use explicit and deterministic Docker base image tags for containerized Python applications
# This is the SHA hash for the `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10` image
# You can get it by running `docker pull public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10` and then `docker images --digests | grep "public.ecr.aws/lambda/python.*3.10"`
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10@sha256:7688a9c4c1a27ea3bfcf12df55cc958e188bb15eea81b463750fe42722e0de87

RUN mkdir src

# Seeing the following warning:
#       Matplotlib created a temporary cache directory at /tmp/matplotlib-4sw1aw8x because the default path (/home/sbx_user1051/.config/matplotlib) is not a writable directory; it is highly recommended to set the MPLCONFIGDIR environment variable to a writable directory, in particular to speed up the import of Matplotlib and to better support multiprocessing.
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827377/setting-matplotlib-mplconfigdir-consider-setting-mplconfigdir-to-a-writable-dir#comment120692932_9947889
# Make a non temporary directory
RUN mkdir /matplotlib_cache
ENV MPLCONFIGDIR="/matplotlib_cache"

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

# Install system dependencies using yum
RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install ffmpeg libSM libXext mesa-libGL && \
    yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src/ ./src/

# https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/16374#issuecomment-580549298
RUN python -c "import matplotlib"
# Still trying to get code to precompile
RUN python -c "from src.calc import process_payload"

CMD ["src/main.lambda_handler"]

Any advice on how to "pre-import" the code and dependencies in the Docker image so that the AWS lambda starts quickly? Please let me know if you need more info.
* Update 1 *
I changed the Dockerfile to use FROM python:3.10-slim and CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"] (also installed uvicorn) and instead built an image and started a container on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu server (droplet).  This results in the container consistently responding to an initial request about 4-5 times faster (~4-6 seconds vs 20-25) on a machine 2 times smaller.
However this isn't a like for like comparison because if I build the same Docker image on the DigitalOcean server but without the RUN python -c "from src.calc import process_payload" then the initial start up time is longer, though harder to measure as the container is just unresponsive, but the initial and subsequent requests to the endpoint is still 4-6 seconds which suggests that the code is already "pre-compiled".  Stopping and restarting the container it then has a fast start up time again as well as requests to it also being 4-6 seconds.
So I think it's some problem with building the image from GitHub's Ubuntu server and uploading it to the AWS ECR that prevents the RUN python -c "from src.calc import process_payload" from helping but also I suspect that using the uvicorn command is also effecting how the container is starting (in a good way).  For now I'll just stick with a self hosted container on DigitalOcean and avoid the AWS Lambda.

This sounds like it might be bytecode compilation time, in which case compileall might help. I don't know much about AWS lambda, though, and 20 seconds sounds like a lot.

What exactly is it that you’re serving that requires 20 direct dependencies? I don’t feel I know enough about the inner bits of Python to opine as to whether or not this could be expedited as is, but I would personally re-evaluate the fundamental architecture of such an implementation and offload as much preprocessing as is possible elsewhere in the stack to preclude sluggish responses to web requests.

Thanks @user2357112 I'll check it out.  I'm just confused because the RUN python -c "from src.calc import process_payload" works locally but seems to have no effect on the docker image...

Thanks @esqew, sorry the question isn't clearer.  I meant that the start up time is 20+ seconds.  In terms of dependencies, I did some profiling and it looks like alphashape and its dependency trimesh are taking the most time to import, sometimes over 10 seconds.  The second and third direct dependency is pandas and rasterio at about 4 seconds each... so those 3 dependencies take about 80%-90% of the import time.

@user2357112 on my local Mac I ran python -m compileall \python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"`` and it helped a bit (~5 seconds speed up) but didn't help significantly improve the initial import time.

Every RUN is a brand new process. Memory is never dumped, only on-disk storage, so anything that's inherently a "load content into memory" operation is unavoidably going to need to start from scratch at process start time.

(You can certainly dump memory and restart each instance from a known state near-instantly with some software stacks -- I've done it with virtual machines invoked as qemu snapshots -- but Docker isn't built for the purpose).

...honestly, when startup latency is the goal, I wouldn't choose Python in the first place; this is something Go does well in particular.

Thanks @CharlesDuffy, yes I can see the performance problems disappear once I run the program once so I assume it's compiling code and saving it to disk?  (At least that's what I see on Mac).  I understand that anything stored in RAM / memory is ephemeral and won't be saved to a docker image.

By running the program more than once, do you mean invoking the same running docker container more than once?  If so, the python environment remains between invocations, meaning heavyweight python packages are still loaded in memory.

Yes, .pyc files get saved to disk to cache Python bytecode -- that's what compileall from the first comment addresses. (Make sure all the libraries you use are getting that treatment, not just your own code or another subset).

Thanks @AnonCoward, yes I wasn't very clear.  I meant that when I install the dependencies on my Mac into a virtual env (not a Docker container) and make a request of the server once and then a second time, the second time is very fast.  With a docker image on an Ubuntu machine it is more confusing what's going on, I've just updated the answer with "Update 1".

Thanks @SiHa but I think that "import does not make any filesytem changes which can be persisted" is not correct. On my Mac the first run of the code is very slow, subsequent runs are fast, I close that shell, open a new one and subsequent runs remain fast.  If I delete and reinstall the venv then it is slow on the first run again.  It must be making changes to the file system no?

...I mean, it's often correct. .pyc files can only be saved by your runtime process if that process has enough permissions to modify its own code, and with a security hat on that's a Bad Idea (you want your runtime operation to be under a less-privileged user than your installation). Which is why it's better to rely on  invoking compileall under a more-privileged account and then using a less-privileged account at runtime.

Got it.  Thanks @CharlesDuffy.  That makes sense.
